# Гифка на bg body

Tags: javascript, html, css

я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы после одного проигрывания гифки, она останавливалась, но при этом моя гифка находится в bg body и я хз как её остановить)))
Ну, или на крайняк, порекомендуйте обработчики гиф, где есть функция где можно остановить зацикливание.

```
body {
      background-image: url(2021-01-12_22-32-00_Trim.gif);
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: В функционале работы с картинками (который вы показали) не предусмотрены операции с "анимацией", попробуйте или воспроизвести анимацию через "контейнер" для анимаций (там или канвас или тег video, или видео-апи). Именно с боди можно разве что костылями: можно словить событие onload что изображение готово к показу, засечь timeout на длинну воспроизведения анимации, а потом присвоить в боди статичное изображение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создание анимации можно отключить то самое повторное воспроизведение анимации, тем самым добиться нужного результата.

Вот например один из ответов из интеренета:

> Открыть эту анимацию в графическом редакторе **GIMP2.6.11**, и просто сохранить, как GIF анимацию, но при сохранении, в окошке "Сохранить как GIF", убрать галочку (чебокс) в строчке -> "Бесконечный цикл".
> Вот и всё!

```css
body {
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/6YtXskw.gif') no-repeat center center / cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

---

Если же не получается, то через JS, но для этого потребуется - узнать тайминг нужного кадра, ну и сам кадр как статичная картинка.

```js
let gifUrl = new Image(), keyUrl = new Image(),
    timing = 2500; // Тайминг, когда нужно заменить картинку
    
gifUrl.src = '//i.imgur.com/vV8Ndee.gif'; // Ссылка на гиф
keyUrl.src = '//i.imgur.com/k4KapkC.gif'; // ссылка на кадр

gifUrl.onload = function(){ // Как загрузится анимация
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${gifUrl.src})`; // Добавляем её к фону 
  setTimeout(function(){ // Запускаем таймер
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${keyUrl.src})`; // Меняем на статичную картинку
  }, timing);
};
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```